# Birt Interactive Report with maximo

Tags: birt, maximo, maximo-anywhere

Here I have a question that is it possible to create an interactive report.

I have a requirement like I have to approve bulk data in Maximo side with birt, in birt report I will keep check boxes who else will run that report they will select that checkboxes if they select the checkbox in the report, the same checkbox need to update in  Maximo record. In Maximo also records contain checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Two examples of how Maximo does this in the out of the box reports would be the Inventory ROP Analysis and Inventory EOQ Analysis reports - both come with the option on the last page to update Maximo with the suggested Economic Order Quantity or Re Order Point data. That's where I'd start.

Comment: Thank you JohnHartin, Can you tell me How Inventory ROP Analysis and Inventory EOQ Analysis reports update Maximo DB, I checked these reports I didn't get how these are working.

Answer (score 0):

The BIRT update reports are interesting.  There are several actually.  The update report is called directly from the runtime report, as @JohnHartin states.  They are not registered directly to the Application.  This is for security reasons.

The update report when executed will take the same input parameters you entered into the runtime report and essentially re-execute the report , except the update report has SQL which writes back to the DB. As mentioned as and example: the ROP Analysis.  You will find the ".rptdesign" file in the {Maximo_home}/reports/birt/reports/INVENTOR folder on your Maximo build machine.  (The report subfolder is the repository you import into BIRT tool to modify your reports.)

From your BIRT workstation navigate to the INVENTOR folder in your project browser and you can then see it in BIRT.  Next, you will be able to open up the design file, (note the update reports have "update" as part of the design file name so real easy to identify.) Then you can examine the SQL in the Initialize method of the report.

Since this report works in conjunction with the Analysis report what happens when you touch the update button on the analysis report, is the data generated in the analysis report is parsed and sent as multiple update SQL transactions back to Maximo DB.  It is incumbent upon you to be very careful making any modifications to the Analysis AND update reports together.

Hope this helps.